# Remove only the first element from a jquery selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div> <!-- Hide -->
<div class="box"></div> <!-- Hide -->
<div class="box"></div> <!-- Hide -->
```

I need to hide all this div but not the first div.

I could do something like this:

```
jQuery('.box').hide();
jQuery('.box').first().show();
```

Is there a way to remove the first `.box` from the array before `.hide()` em?

Comment: Performance comparison of submitted answers: http://jsperf.com/remove-only-the-first-element-from-a-jquery-selection

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
jQuery('.box').slice(1).hide()
```

Comment: +1, best way to go (and `slice` is an under-utilized feature).

Comment: +1 for simple solution. Attention: "Is there a way to remove the **first**...", if you want to remove **the first one** you have to use `.slice(0)`. :-)

Comment: @John to remove the first element from a jquery set you need to use slice(1) not slice(0), the slice method uses a zero-based index but the new slice is sliced _before_ the index. So slice(1) slices the set _before_ the element with index 1 (ie before the 2nd element) in effect removing the first element. slice(0) cuts before the first element so it just returns the entire original set.

Answer (score 13):

```
jQuery('.box:not(:first)').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8wMFc/

Comment: I'd say *this* is the cleanest answer of the bunch

Answer (score 6):

try

```
jQuery('.box').not(':first').hide();
```

**comparison:**

@T.J.Crowder is right the code i have suggested does the extra parsing that can be avoided by `.slice` as suggested by @zch

[**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z9GsY/3/) is the profile of my code **(0.8ms)** and [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9mt7b/) is the profile of @zch's code **(0.53ms)** see the difference

Comment: I am in doubt if accept your answer or zch answer with slice(1)

Comment: Well I believe this is the most readable code, I will accept this.

Comment: @yes123: The downside being parsing and applying the selector when there's really no need for that big a hammer. But unless you're in a really tight loop doing this thousands of times, it's not like it matters. :-)

Comment: I don't have any loop, I just need it executed once, so accepted this

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('.box').not(':eq(0)').hide();
```

That said, I prefer Residual Envy's solution.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
jQuery('.box:gt(0)').hide();
```